# Validate JWT in Azure APIM policy

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In Azure APIM, I am trying to create a policy that will validate a JWT. No matter what I try, I always get a "401: Invalid JWT" error.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  (Maybe I'm not using the right signing key?)

My base64 encoded security key is `Zm9v`.

I create sample token at jwt.io and so my Authorization header is:

```
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.Bm8tu4m18oA96xwhBL8AV_4hRpIU6OrK5UaOmGqBEsk
```

Here's the policy I am using:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt
            header-name="Authorization"
            require-expiration-time="false"
            require-scheme="Bearer"
        >
            <issuer-signing-keys>
                <key>Zm9v</key>
            </issuer-signing-keys>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

HTTP Response:

```
cache-control: private
content-length: 48
content-type: application/json
ocp-apim-trace-location: https://xxxxxxx
vary: Origin
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "message": "Invalid JWT."
}
```

Comment: What's the details error message?

Comment: I added the HTTP response to be question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem was my key size was too small.

When testing the API in Azure, there is a Trace tab, but it is missing the On Error section.

[image]

You have to go to the Message tab. There is an `ocp-apim-trace-location` which will show the full trace.
[image]

It turns out the key size I was using was too small.  It was only 24 and needs to be at least 128.
[image]

Comment: This was really helpful for me! I though that "invalid jwt" was the only error I would get and it was hopeless to work with!

Answer (score -1):

The token you provided is **invalid signature**. Go to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to check your token firstly.

The policy you provided it right. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies).

Comment: It seems valid.  I pasted "Zm9v" into the secret textbox, checked the "secret base64 encoded" checkbox, and then pasted the JWT into the token textbox.  It says "Signature Verified".